# .then() is not working in setInterval function while passing parameter?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Below is my code I'm getting this error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): startPolling.bind(...).then is not a function`

```
 setInterval(startPolling.bind(null, id).then(function(response){
       if (response.id == 0){
         console.log("stop polling")
       }
     }), 2000)


 function startPolling(id){
  return callApi('/someUrl/'+id+'','get') // it returns a promise
 }
```

problem:
 If I'm not using `bind` while calling `startPolling` then `setInterval` is not executing  the code at every 2 seconds.

If i use `bind` while calling `startPolling` setInterval is executing the way it does, but `then()` is not executing since I'm getting the above mentioned error

Comment: startPolling.bind(...).then is not a function it is a promise

Comment: if it's a promise then why I'm getting this error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): startPolling.bind(...).then is not a function`

Comment: what do you get by running it outside the setInterval() ? try to run it and add a catch in the chain and check err

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startPolling.bind` returns a new function which when called will call `startPolling` which in turn will return a promise. If anything it needs to be `startPolling.bind(null, id)().then`… which is obviously nonsense.

You can't `bind` here. You can't call a function later but access a property on its return value immediately. Use a callback wrapper:

```
setInterval(function () {
    startPolling(id).then(...)
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to answer your question more thoroughly I would need some more debugging, e.g. console.log on your `startPolling`. To test the scenario: If you remove `.bind` would the startPolling still fire, but maybe give an error (which you currently don't catch) thus not starting the interval?

A way I would program to poll an async function in an interval is the following:

```
public startIntervalPolling(id, intervalDuration=2000) {
    var intervalVariable = setInterval(
        startPolling(id).then((response) => {
          console.log("Polling response", response);
          if (response.id == 0) {
            clearInterval(intervalVariable);
          }
        }, (pollingError) => {
          console.error("Error while polling", pollingError)
        }), intervalDuration);
  }
```

Haven't tested it, but hopes this helps you in the right direction.